# WCF Client Soap Security Header - UsernameToken & BinarySecurityToken Empty

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm trying to create a Soap request with security header like this :

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:Username>SomeUserName</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password>SomePassword</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">MII...SomeTokenString...
    </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Here's what I've tried but this results in UsernameToken and BinarySecurityToken being empty.

App.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType ="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="67...thumbprint...4b" x509FindType ="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://name.myserver.com/myservice/v1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior"
    contract="ServiceReferenceMyService.MyService" name="MyServiceEP">
    <identity>
      <dns value ="CertName" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

C# code:

```
UsernameToken usernameToken = new UsernameToken("SomeUserName", "SomePassword", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);

var cert = new X509Certificate2("D:\\CertName.pfx", "SomePassword");
var export = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, "SomePassword");
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(export);
X509SecurityToken securityToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert);

SecurityHeaderType securityHeaderType = new SecurityHeaderType();
securityHeaderType.Any = new System.Xml.XmlElement[2];
securityHeaderType.Any[0] = usernameToken.GetXml(new System.Xml.XmlDocument());
securityHeaderType.Any[1] = securityToken.GetXml(new System.Xml.XmlDocument());

ChannelFactory<MyService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>("MyServiceEP");

MyService client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
GetProductDataRequestResponse responseData = client.GetProductData(new GetProductDataRequestRequest(securityHeaderType, serviceContext, requestData));

((IChannel)client).Close();
channelFactory.Close();
```

Please disregard the two objects serviceContext and requestData -
serviceContext is a custom class to pass data required by the service
requestData is the request data (filter criteria) sent to the service for which results are expected.

The above code causes the soap request header to look like this but **empty tags showing Removed is a problem**. I want the actual values to appear. I also don't need the wsse:Nonce and wsu:Created elements either.

```
<s:Header>
    <h:Security xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-01f8a086-92b5-4aa2-8154-244061bdae5e" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>
                <!-- Removed-->
            </wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>
                <!-- Removed-->
            </wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce>
                <!-- Removed-->
            </wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-02-25T00:20:25Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <!-- Removed-->
        </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </h:Security>
</s:Header>
```

Can someone please point out what am I missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!